# Eigen values for matrix at each grid point

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, lapack

I have a 3d grid. At each grid point, I have a matrix. I would like to find eigen values and eigen vectors of this matrix at each grid point using python. I am doing something like this.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
n = 256
s = np.zeros((3,3,n,n,n))
#s is calculated by a formula here, this part is correct
e = np.zeros((3,n,n,n))
e[0:3,:,:,:] = LA.eigvals(s[0:3,0:3,:,:,:])
```

It gives following error,

```
1 n = 256
2 e = np.zeros(((3),n,n,n))
----> 3 e[0:3,:,:,:] = LA.eigvals(s[0:3,0:3,:,:,:])

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3,256,256) into shape (3,256,256,256)
```

Since it is a large array, using loops is taking a lot of time. I actually have to do it for many such cubic grids. Is there a way to avoid loops ? The code has to understand that the at each grid point, there is a matrix whose eigen values are needed, it is not a 5 cross 5 matrix.

Comment: `LA.eigvals` accepts a matrix of shape `(..., M, M)`, where the last two dimensions are the axes over which the eigenvalues are calculated (see the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigvals.html#numpy.linalg.eigvals)). Don't worry about pre-allocating `e` in this case, which is where the error is coming from. What is the matrix size at each grid point? 3x3? If so, you'll want the `s` matrix to be in the shape (n,n,n,3,3).

Comment: @pstjohn: yes, it is 3 cross 3 matrix at each point. I would try your solution and get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment and offer some actual code, you could get this to work with your existing matrices with some array reshaping:

```
eigs = np.linalg.eigvals(s.swapaxes(0, -1).swapaxes(1,-2))
e = eigs.swapaxes(0,-1)
```

will give you a matrix with

```
>>> e.shape()
(3, 256, 256, 256)
```

Comment: Perfect. I am able to calculate eigen values and eigen vectors at gird points. Sorting the eigen values in order is also fine but having trouble with eigen vecs. Can you please check: `a = np.zeros((3,3,2,2,2)) a[:,:,0,0,0] = [[5,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,3]] a[:,:,1,1,1] = [[2,0,0],[0,3,0],[0,0,1]] eigvals,eigvecs = LA.eig(a.swapaxes(0, -1).swapaxes(1,-2)) ev = eigvals.swapaxes(0,-1) evecs = eigvecs.swapaxes(0,-1).swapaxes(1,-2) evo = np.sort(ev,axis=0) eveco = evecs[np.argsort(ev,axis=0),:] print np.shape(eveco)' It gives (3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2) instead of (3,3,2,2,2)